# Fully secured gateway web sites

Tags: security, website, encryption, gateway

Are there any web sites that serve as gateways for fully encrypted communication? I mean sites with which I can open a secured session, and then to exchange through them with other sites in a secure way both URLs and content?

**Update:**

I was wondering if there was a way to access any site over the Internet (http or https) without letting any Intranet-proxy read the requested URL or the received content.

My question is whether such a site exists, e.g.: I am connected to that site via https, I send it a URL in a secured way, the site gets the content from the target site (possibly in a non-secured way) and returns to me the requested content in a secured way.

Comment: What do you exactly need? HTTPS already does that without the third site.

Answer (score 0):

Depends exactly why you want to do this. Content encryption happens through https so don't worry about that.

As to why you want the URL hidden - what is the purpose? If it is anonymity you want, you could look at [TOR](http://www.torproject.org/).